# g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command, MinGW

Tags: g++, mingw

I am running windows 8 x64. I have just installed the GNU C++ compiler through MinGW.

When I try to test this in the command line I get:

> g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command

If I change to the directory c:/MinGW/bin and run g++ it works.

I have set the path to c:/MinGW/bin. This appears when I enter echo %path% and I have tried restarting my computer after changing the path variable.

I've searched the internet and the advice I've gotten back is change the path variable. I have done this and I am looking for a different solution to this problem.

Comment: Does `gcc` work? And have you e.g. cygwin installed too?

Comment: Also make sure you have `\` used (as other entries in Path).

Comment: Duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: Are you running from a `cmd.exe` prompt, a Cygwin prompt, or an MSYS bash prompt? Paste into your question the output of the `path` command.  What does the command `c:\mingw\bin\g++ -v` say?

Comment: cygwin is not installed
I am running it from cmd.exe